# A special rule for a directory in .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?p=$1 [QSA]
```

I'd like to create an exception of the last rule: if the user enters `example.com/somefoldername` It should not redirect to `index.php?p=somefoldername`, but to `./somefoldername/index.php`.

It is a very easy task I guess! But can't come up with a solution. I tried

`RewriteCond ^somefoldername$ somefoldername/index.php` but it didn't work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(somefoldername)/?$ $1/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work. It causes "Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log."

Comment: There was a mistake in my answer that is fixed now. Try my updated rule now.